# arecord no such file or directory error when running via cron

Tags: pi-3b+, cron, arecord

So I can run:

`arecord -d 9 -f S16_LE -c 1 -r44100 -t wav /home/pi/signal_9s.wav`

from terminal and it works as expected. It records for 9 seconds and saves to the signal_9s.wav file. However if I set this up to run from a cron job, I get :

`arecord: main:828: audio open error: No such file or directory`.

If I specify the hardware option `-D hw:2,0` in my cron command, then it works, but the card that my microphone is assigned to seems to change when I run my pi connected to a monitor versus when I run my pi without a monitor, so if the pi can find the microphone without me having to specify that would solve a bunch of problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Revised Answer:

`arecord` needs an *environment* variable called `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to locate the resources it needs. By default our `cron` jobs run in a different *environment* than (for example) the one in our interactive shell, and the `cron` environment won't (by default) include the variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

The solution then is to add this environment variable in your `crontab`. Once `cron` has this environment variable, it should run it with no complaints. Here's how to do this:

1. Open your `crontab` for editing:

```bsh
$ crontab -e
```

2. With your `crontab` open in the editor, add the following line *above* the line you use to start `arecord`:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

I've used `1000` as the `uid` here as that is default for user `pi` in RPi OS. You can verify this by entering `id pi` a the command line.

***For future reference:***
The *environment* in `cron` is [austere](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/austere), at least in part, to reduce the risk of potential security issues. Sometimes, we need to know just exactly **what** the `cron` environment is... How do we do that? The easiest and best way I've found to do this is to ask `cron` to tell us! We add the `printenv` command in our `crontab`, and redirect it to a file in our home directory:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep; /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/mycronenv.txt 2>&1
```

This will give you a handy reference file containing your `cron` environment, updated each time you `reboot`. You can compare it against the `printenv` output from your interactive shell the next time your `cron` job misfires :)

#### Original Answer:

Try using `/usr/bin/arecord` instead of `arecord` in your `crontab` entry.

`cron` runs in a different *environment* than the one you have in your interactive shell. It doesn't know where `arecord` is - so you must tell it.

I don't know enough about `arecord` to understand the effect of specifying the "hardware option", but try this first & we'll go from there.

---

EDIT:

According to [this Ubuntu Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681957/arecord-does-not-work-with-crontab), there is an *environment* variable associated with the use of `arecord` (XDG_RUNTIME_DIR), and it is dependent on the `userid`.

This answer doesn't explain things extremely well, but there is another [answer that seems to do a better job of explanation.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir).

Your difficulty here is due to the fact that `cron` does **not** have the same *environment* as you do from your *interactive shell*, and it does not have the same *environment* as you do in your *windowing/X* environment. And so, the solution must be to provide `cron` the *environment variable* that contains your hardware information.

I can't try this on my machine because: a) it is RPi Lite (no desktop/windows), and b) no microphone. Therefore, I will only suggest that you try adding the following line to your `crontab` file somewhere above the line you invoke `arecord`:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

*Note: I assume user pi & UID = 1000*

Please also note that this was adapted from the **Ubuntu** example, and while the approach may be good, things may be arranged differently in RPi OS - IOW, you may have to tweak this some :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried using `/usr/bin/arecord` in the cron entry and the same problem occurs `audio open error: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: Did you specify the hardware option?

Comment: Yeah, if I specify the hardware option it works (even with `/usr/bin/arecord` instead of just `arecord`). The problem is when I don't specify the hardware option.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: I've not used `arecord`, so this will be a *wag*, but: Is it possible that the hardware option is set as part of your *environment*? You could check this by running `printenv` from the CLI. Also, setting hardware options sometimes requires `sudo` privileges - do you or did you use `sudo` in setting this up? FWIW, the change in *environment* between `cron` and the interactive shell (`bash` likely) is the ***most likely suspect*** when someone says, "It works from the command line, but not in `cron`". I'll wait for yr cmt & we'll try something else if this doesn't pan out.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: 
Look for something like `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in your `printenv` output. Also see the edit I have made in my answer... I am "shooting in the dark" as I cannot replicate your setup, but I'm confident this is the correct ***approach***; i.e. it may need to be tweaked!

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. This is great. I won't get a chance to play with this until tomorrow evening at the earliest, but I will let you know. Thanks again, for taking your time!

Comment: Perfect. I ran printenv, and sure enough `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` was there. I added that to the cron, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your patience and your time!

Comment: @ChaseRoberts: Glad it worked out :)